# time complexity Θ(n log n)

Tags: time, complexity-theory

if algorithm A has time complexity Θ(n log n) and runs for 10^3 ms on a problem of size 10^4, about how long would you expect it to take to solve a problem of size 10^6?

A.1.5×10^5 ms

B. 10^5 ms

C. 10^6 ms

D.2×10^6 ms

E. 2.4 × 10^8 ms

can anyone tell me how to solve this question?

Comment: How do you think should this problem be approached?

Comment: A is the correct answer but i don't know where the 1.5 come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run-time is proportional to the growth rate.

This implies that if complexity is Θ(n log n) then 10<sup>3</sup> ∝ (10<sup>4</sup> * Log(10<sup>4</sup>)). In other words, you can say that the run-time (whose value is 10<sup>3</sup>) = k * n * log(n) = k * 10<sup>4</sup> * Log(10<sup>4</sup>) where k is the proportionality constant.

- So, k can be computed to 10<sup>3</sup> / (10<sup>4</sup> * Log(10<sup>4</sup>)) = 1 / (40 * Log(10)).

For a problem of size 10<sup>6</sup>,

- the running time would be k * 10<sup>6</sup> * log(10<sup>6</sup>).
- which comes to: 10<sup>6</sup> * log(10<sup>6</sup>) / (40 * Log(10)).
- or, equal to 1.5 * 10<sup>5</sup>

Comment: this k computed to 104 / (103 * Log(103)) = 1 / (40 * Log(10))?

Comment: y there is division in the function(104 / (103 * Log(103)))?

Comment: @EmilyLiu: Updated. Let me know if you didn't understand even now.